# German Phd vs Swedish Phd vs Norway Phd

Tags: phd, job-search

What phd is more capable of getting a job in industry in European countries? (in Engineering field)

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately, this site is not the right place for the question (it will get closed and downvoted, without any answers). You will have to find your answer yourself;)

Comment: Hard for me to imagine a difference except that Norway isn't part of EU. All high quality as far as I know.

Comment: Obviously a PhD from country X is better for getting a job in country X. However, the stature of the university is more important and, in the grand scheme of things, the country doesn't really matter. It's like asking "What car is fastest? A red one, a green one, or a blue one?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the above.  Treat all those countries as one unit, apply in all three and take the best you can get.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question about getting a job in industry, unless you assume that there is a way to say which of the ones the OP can get is the best for industry.